# ThreeJS cloning triangles then rotating them individually

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have the following code: https://pastebin.com/sxfmAAz9 (using pastebin because I don't want to distract from the OP, it's a bit of a long sequence)

Basically I'm creating a plane and splitting it into widthsegments and heightsegments in order to create a spiky plane. I am then iterating over each face and I'm trying to duplicate that face so I can make it go up and rotate slowly so it looks like it's coming out of the plane. I've successfully done this however when I rotate the triangles, it looks like they're grouped together, like they're part of the same mesh even though I am creating a new mesh for every face. Here's how I am creating the triangles:

```
if (numberOfTriangles < possibleFloatingTriangles) {
  var randomIndices = [];

  while (randomIndices.length < possibleFloatingTriangles - numberOfTriangles) {
    var randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*150);
    if (randomIndices.indexOf(randomNumber) > -1) continue;
    randomIndices[randomIndices.length] = randomNumber;
  }

  scene.traverse(function (node) {
    if (numberOfTriangles >= possibleFloatingTriangles) return;

    if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh && node.geometry.type === "PlaneGeometry") {
      for(var i = 0; i < node.geometry.faces.length; i++) {
        if(randomIndices.indexOf(i) != -1) {
          var currentFace = node.geometry.faces[i];
          var triangleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

          // I assumed they might be getting referenced here initially hence the clone()
          var p1 = node.geometry.vertices[currentFace.a].clone();
          var p2 = node.geometry.vertices[currentFace.b].clone();
          var p3 = node.geometry.vertices[currentFace.c].clone();

          triangleGeometry.vertices.push(p1);
          triangleGeometry.vertices.push(p2);
          triangleGeometry.vertices.push(p3);

          var face = new THREE.Face3(0,2,1);

          triangleGeometry.faces.push(face);

          var triangleMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, wireframe: showWireframe, specular: 0x0, morphTargets: true, flatShading: true, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
          var triangle = new THREE.Mesh(triangleGeometry, triangleMaterial);

          triangle.rotation.set(-Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2000, Math.PI); ;

          scene.add(triangle);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I basically make the individual triangle meshes that I duplicate from the plane rotate around themselves? I don't want them grouped, I want each triangle to be individual. Right now all triangles are behaving as if they're part of the same mesh, if I am rotating their individual geometry it looks as if I am rotating a plane where they're all situated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the origin of each triangle is still at `0, 0, 0`. You're rotating all triangles around the same pivot point, giving the impression that they're all connected. What you need to do is use [translate](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Geometry.translate) on the geometry to place its vertices around the origin, and then return it to its original spot by changing the [position](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D.position) of the mesh back to its original values:

For example, pretend you have a triangle that you want to rotate around the point `[5, 3, 0]`:

```
// First, translate geometry to origin
triangleGeometry.translate(-5, -3, 0);
var triangleMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, wireframe: showWireframe, specular: 0x0, morphTargets: true, flatShading: true, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
var triangle = new THREE.Mesh(triangleGeometry, triangleMaterial);
// Then move mesh back to its starting position
triangle.position.set(5, 3, 0);
```

How you calculate the center of each triangle, I'll leave up to you :)